# Error 403 Forbidden when including javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a couple pieces of code that should grab a form from another website. The php in the header sanitizes the GET string in the URL.
Basically I have a page: order.html, which works if I paste the entire javascript function in it like so:

```
<?php  if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
            echo file_get_contents("http://".sanitizeString($_GET['url']));
        }
function sanitizeString($var) {
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    return stripslashes($var);
} ?>


<html>
<body>
<p>html text still displays</p>
<script>
document.write("<div id='info'></div>");
nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000
request = new ajaxRequest()
request.open("GET", "<?php echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); ?>?url=platform.leedhub.com/merchants/form.php?merchant_id=<?php echo $_GET['merchantid']; ?>&margin=<?php echo $_GET['affiliateid'] ?>&padding=<?php echo $_GET['URL'] ?>" + nocache, true);
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (this.status == 200)
        {
            if (this.responseText != null)
            {
                document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
                this.responseText
            }
            else alert("Ajax error: No data received")
        }
        else alert( "Ajax error: " + this.statusText)
    }
}
request.send(null)
    function ajaxRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
        }
        catch(e1)
        {
            try
            {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch(e2)
            {
                try
                {
                    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                }
                catch(e3)
                {
                    request = false
                }
            }
        }
        return request
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**However, it will not work if I take the written javascript and include it from an external url.**

```
<?php  if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
echo file_get_contents("http://".sanitizeString($_GET['url']));
}
function sanitizeString($var) {
$var = strip_tags($var);
$var = htmlentities($var);
return stripslashes($var);
} ?>
<p>html text still displays</p>
<html>
<body>
<script src="urlget.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting a 403 Forbidden Error. It's telling me from request.send(null).

**Access Forbidden
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.**

Do you have any idea how I can remedy this? I need the script to be an external file so I can include it on multiple websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a file system permission issue. You must make sure that the web server has read access on the `urlget.js` file. You have to find out as which user is running the worker of the web server and give to that user read permission for `urlget.js` file.

Comment: Interesting. I'm currently running this on a localhost (installed with XAMPP) on Windows. I was under the impression that there were no permissions that needed to be changed with windows.